# How big areas/.osm data files can Maperitive handle?

Tags: maperitive, file-size, limitations

How do the file-size limitations of [Maperitive](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive) work out?

Background: I'm interested in making a map of the whole of Germany. Any pre-generated maps I find online only cover a region at a time, so maybe most mapping software has a limit.

Would it help if I make a .osm file with some features removed? Basically I only need streets and street numbers of civilized areas - so Schwarzwald might be ok to skip :-)

Comment: I think you mean Maperitive (rather than Maperative) so have corrected your question and added a link accordingly.  If I got that wrong you should be able to rollback the edit.

Comment: according to this question https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/maperitive/5JIraqyWCAM maperitive holds the complete map in ram and filtering out any mapfeatures you dont need should decrease the necessary ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Maperitive loads everything into RAM, so Germany as a whole would probably not work in Maperitive. It just wasn't designed for such a scenario, more for smaller areas (cities. regions, smaller countries). Maybe if you used some kind of pre-filtering to remove unneeded features (or areas) it would work, but I wouldn't get my hopes too high - Germany's OSM data coverage is quite dense.

I'm working on another piece of software (called Azurite, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uPPUuNpUIQ&list=UUB_BTUx1wcmnENQXj0UtT4g) that will be able to "swallow" larger OSM datasets. I don't know when the release date will be though. Still a lot to do.

Comment: Thanks, so Maperative is RAM-limited, and my main task means I'll need to filter OSM data. And hunt down a method to create vector-based MBtiles.
Thanks for the video; Azurite seems interesting too!